# Batch update user account passwords on multiple servers

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2012, scripting

I have a script to update user ID and passwords every 90 days due to security issues. With this script, I have to manually go to every server and run the batch script. I have roughly 60 odd servers in my domain.

Is there any way I can mass update all the servers?

Here is the script

```
@echo off
net user Username P@ssw0rd /add /comment:"Wintel Administrator" /passwordchg:Yes /fullname:"hello"
wmic useraccount where "name='Username'" set passwordexpires=True
net localgroup "Administrators" Username /add
net user Username insertPW
net user Username insertPW
net user Username insertPW
exit
```

Comment: Why are you not using Active Directory?

Comment: All are individual servers which are not tied with AD due to security issues.

Comment: It is completely preposterous that you are making the assumption that having 180 non-centrally-managed accounts that require manual work to maintain and no way to enforce policy on them is in any way more secure than AD.

Comment: Yes I do understand that, the previous guy left me in such a state whereby i have to clean up his mess. I will feedback to management on this. Thank you @EEAA, please close this question if possible.

Comment: Not to mention all the time and money you're wasting by not having AD.

Comment: Use the LAPS tool to manage the local accounts- there is no need for more than one administrator account

Comment: You want to change passwords many times a year due to a security issue? Why not fix the security issue instead?

Comment: I get that this is an upsetting question to many but I think it's quite interesting and left open could help anyone looking for answers to similar situations rethink and resolve the underlying problem instead of using the dirty and somewhat preposterous quick fix :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use psexec (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx)

With psexec you can run commands on every computer in your network.

for example: set up a .txt where all your computernames are. with psexec you can now run it like this (as a user with administrator permission on each computer you want to update)

```
psexec @C:\computers.txt cmd /c "call Filepath\yourbat.bat"
```

but i would, as suggested in the comments definetly set up AD